# Can't run a build in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have problems with some configuration of my TeamCity project.
I'm trying to build an application in order to run its Unit Tests, but i can't.

It seems that my project have problems to get the source from git, which is a private repo:

```
Build 'Myproject :: Build Myproject' #15 
Started 'Fri Jun 29 12:41:28 EDT 2012' on 'Default Agent' by 'you'
Finished 'Fri Jun 29 12:41:47 EDT 2012' with status 'ERROR Unable to collect changes'
TeamCity URL http://ieditedthispart.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8111/viewLog.html?buildId=16&buildTypeId=bt2 
TeamCity server version is 7.0.3 (build 21424)

[12:41:29]: bt2
[12:41:29]: Checking for changes
[12:41:47]: [PREPARATION_FAILURE_TYPE]
[12:41:47]: Failed to start build
[12:41:47]: Failed to collect changes, error: 'git fetch' command failed.
stderr: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.pack.BinaryDelta.apply(BinaryDelta.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.pack.BinaryDelta.apply(BinaryDelta.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.resolveDeltas(PackParser.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.resolveDeltas(PackParser.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.resolveDeltas(PackParser.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryPackParser.parse(ObjectDirectoryPackParser.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.receivePack(BasePackFetchConnection.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpFetchConnection.doFetch(TransportHttp.java:64...
[12:41:47]: Build finished
```

As you can see, is alerting about Java Out of Memory, but it doesn't make sense because its running with at least 1300MB of heap size.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that was a problem with the JAVA heap size or memory options at startup TeamCity.

I had to set the following environment variables:

```
export TEAMCITY_SERVER_MEM_OPTS="-Xmx1300m -XX:MaxPermSize=270m"
export TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS="-Dteamcity.git.fetch.separate.process=false"
```